# Relation between bels and decibles

Tags: circuit-analysis, bode-plot, decibel

Following is a sreenshot from "Fundamentals of electric circuits by Alexander and Sadiku". In 14.4 he defines "bels" and then in 14.5 the "decibels". I don't understand the line just above 14.5 that the decible provides us a unit of less magnitude but it should be larger as bels is multiplied with ten and not with deci( also why we call it decibels as bels is not multipied with deci but with ten).

[image]

Comment: 'Dec' is the root word for '10', as in decimetre (1/10 metre) and decimal (base 10 numbering). A decibel is 1/10 of a Bel and is a more manageable unit.

Comment: Wow. Two good pages of text wasted only to ask what 'deci' means.

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deci- is a prefix meaning 1/10. deca- would be the prefix for 10.

The quantity being measured is P2/P1, and you are multiplying the log of it by 10 so more of the smaller units are required for a given P2/P1. Imagine the weight of a (small) person is 50kg. If you multiply that number by 1000 you get the weight (50,000) of that same person in the smaller units of 1g.

It's more convenient to use dB rather than bels because, in many cases, you don't need fractions of a dB.